# Undefined offset php al recorrer Array PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando recorrer el siguiente `array`:

```
([items] => Array(
           [1] => Array
               (
                [productCode] => DIEZ MIL 10,000 NEGRO 34
                [cantidad] => 1
                [precio] => 1
               )
           [2] => Array(
                [productCode] => DIEZ MIL 10,000 NEGRO 35
                [cantidad] => 1
                [precio] => 1
               )
           [4] => Array(
                [productCode] => DIEZ MIL 10,000 CAFE 39
                [cantidad] => 1
                [precio] => 1
              )
           )
```

pero me da el error

> Undefined offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El **`Undefined offset`** se presenta cuando intentas acceder  a un elemento del array que no existe.

Para recorrer **UN** `array` lo más sencillo sería un `foreach` , Si los datos que quieres obtener requiere este camino para llegar a ellos. *(comoelejemploexpuesto)*

`Array [ Array { Array (Valores) : Array(Valores) : Array(Valores) } ]`

**Es decir un `foreach` por cada `Array` Interno** *(tres en total)*

```
$array = array('items' =>array(
array(
    'productCode' => 'DIEZ MIL 10,000 NEGRO 34',
    'cantidad' => 1,
    'precio' => 1
),
array(
    'productCode' => 'DIEZ MIL 10,000 NEGRO 35',
    'cantidad' => 2,
    'precio' => 2
),
array(
    'productCode' => 'DIEZ MIL 10,000 CAFE 39',
    'cantidad' => 3,
    'precio' => 3
) 
));   

foreach ($array as $key => $value) { /* Array Items */
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){ /* Siguiente  Array */
        foreach($value2 as $key3=> $value3)/* Siguiente  Array (3) */
            echo $key3 .  "-- " .$value3 . "<br>";
    }
 }

/*  Otra forma de acceder */

foreach($array as $key => $value){
  for ($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++) { 
    echo ("Producto : " . $value[$i]['productCode'] . " Cantidad : " . $value[$i]['cantidad'] . " Precio : " .$value[$i]['precio']);
    echo "<br>" ;
 }
}
```